# What else was inside Ben Kenobi's chest?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

Form the movie *Star Wars: Episode IV – A New Hope*, we all remember the scene at Ben Kenobi's hut where the old hermit gets up and goes to a chest where he rummages around and then extracts from it Anakin's lightsaber. Aside from that elegant weapon of a more civilized age, I wonder what else was inside that chest.

[image: Alec Guinness "Obi-Wan Ben' Kenobi" screen used Lightsaber chest from Star Wars: Episode IV – A New Hope]

By the way, LEGO Star Wars A New Hope Obi-Wan's Hut #75270 comes with a Marksman-H combat remote that is placed inside the chest along with the weapon.

[image: Detail from LEGO Star Wars A New Hope Obi-Wan's Hut #75270]

**UPDATE:** I only have the 1080p (x264) mp4 of the movie [1920 x 816] and have been trying to augment a bit what is visible inside Kenobi's chest. So far, I have spotted a golden object that can be seen from two different angles. I can't identify it yet, but probably some of you, with a better resolution movie, could help me with it. Here two still pictures showing the golden object with augmented details.

[image: Still picture of Star Wars A New Hope]

[image: Still picture of Star Wars A New Hope]

Comment: Was it his heart?

Comment: Came here half-expecting a cross-franchise question.

Comment: They filmed in Tunisia, so I bet they picked the chest up there.

Comment: "*All sorts of intriguing items were removed and shoved around, only to be placed back in the bin. A few of them Luke recognized. As Kenobi was obviously intent on something important, he forbore inquiring about any of the other tantalizing flotsam.*" - [Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel))

Comment: *"Luke moved down into the small living area, where he found a vacuum-seal chest on the floor beside a structural column. It was from this chest that Ben had extracted Luke's first lightsaber, the same lightsaber that Ben claimed had previously belonged to Luke's father. Luke brushed the sand from the chest's lid, then lifted it and looked inside. **It was empty.**"* - [The Life and Legend of Obi-Wan Kenobi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Life_and_Legend_of_Obi-Wan_Kenobi)

Comment: The remote that Luke uses is Han's, not Obi-Wan's

Comment: @Valorum I no longer have a copy of the book, but fwiw, I found a few other relevant results in TLaLoOWK for "box". There's a scene that seems to describe Obi-Wan putting items in the chest, as well as Luke finding a book and apparently being mistaken that the box was empty, but I couldn't get enough of a relevant preview in Google Books to read the whole scenes.

Comment: @MiloP - The boa-wood box isn't inside the (empty) chest, it's elsewhere, in Obi-Wan's small workshop. "*Then Luke spotted the box. It was an intricately carved boa-wood box, resting on the floor between the workbench and small auxiliary generator. Luke was moving the glowrod closer to the box when a sudden sound came from above."*

Comment: That box contains a variety of interesting items, but they're not in the chest; *"Peering past the flashpacket, Luke saw that the box contained some rectangular objects. He recognized them as books. Although he was far more familiar with datapads for information storage, he had seen enough books in his lifetime to know how what they were and how to use them. The largest book was a leather-bound volume that appeared quite ancient. Luke picked it up, and noticed that it too was sealed by a thumbclasp.*

Comment: We see [inside the chest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtUTf.jpg) in the 2016 Graphic Novelisation, but we can't really make out any of the items. Possibly a spare robe or some paperwork?

Comment: This Kenner Luke Skywalker figure came with Obi-Wan's chest and a variety of stuff; A lightsaber, a remote drone, his aquata breather, etc; https://www.therpf.com/forums/attachments/obi-wan-chest-s6-036-luke-jpg.1425571/ / https://www.therpf.com/forums/attachments/review_lukeskywalkeranhtsc023-jpg.1425568/

Comment: A fine set of sparkly math rocks that he does not get the opportunity to use as often as he likes, a book of 501 sudoku, and a half-full bottle of That Ole Janx Spirit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Canon answer: unknown, possibly his journal

It's unclear whether it had been in the chest, but in the fifth issue of the 2015 *Star Wars* comic series, Luke returns to Ben Kenobi's home and finds it ransacked, except for a box labeled "For Luke". This turns out to contain [Obi-Wan's journal](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Journals_of_Ben_Kenobi). While it's possible that Obi-Wan had had a more secure hiding place for this box before his house was scavenged, he apparently didn't think he needed one for Anakin's lightsaber.

The 2016 edition of *Complete Locations* identifies the chest as a "vacuum-sealed chest" containing Anakin's lightsaber, "which Obi-Wan had been waiting to give to Luke", but doesn't expand on the rest of its contents.

Comment: The second part of this answer is incorrect. The box (as revealed in *The Life and Legends of Obi-Wan Kenobi*) was always to be found in the basement of Obi-Wan's dwelling, not in the chest - *"Luke stared hard at the keypad. Ben had never mentioned this box **in his basement**, and Luke could only imagine what the access code might be."*

Comment: @Valorum Fixed, thanks - SotE doesn't specify where the trunk was, so I'm not sure if this was a retcon by later authors or if it was always intended to be a different trunk.